# Proof of an equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let S be the relation on R deﬁned by $xSy  \Leftrightarrow x=|y|$, $\forall x,y\in\Re$

Is the relation reflexive, symmetric and/or transitive?

By my proof that

1) $x=|y| \Rightarrow |y|=x$ (reflexive)
2) $x=|y| \wedge|x|=y$  (symmetric)
3) But not transitive because not exist $z:xSy \wedge ySz s.t. xSz$

Right?

Comment: Consider $x=1$, $y=-1$. Then $x=|y|$, but not $y=|x|$. So it's not symmetric.

Comment: And it *is* transitive, since if $x=|y|$ and $y=|z|$, then $y\geq 0$, from which we obtain $x=|y|=y=|z|$.

Comment: It's not reflexive either, consider $x=-1$. Then $-1 \neq |-1|$ so $(-1)S(-1)$ is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope no one minds if I assemble the various comments by Cloudscape and coffeemath (and myself) into an answer.

- For reflexivity, you want to show that $xSx$, or $x=|x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Clearly this is not true for any negative values of $x$, so $S$ is not reflexive.
- For symmetry, you want to show that $xSy$ implies $ySx$, or that whenever $x=|y|$, we also have $y=|x|$. This also fails whenever $y$ is negative, so $S$ is not symmetric.
- For transitivity, you want to show that $xSy$ and $ySz$ imply $xSz$, or in other words that if $x=|y|$ and $y=|z|$, then $x=|z|$. This one *is* true, since if $y=|z|$ then $y$ must be non-negative, so it follows that $|y|=y$. Then you have $x=|y|=y=|z|$, so transitivity holds.